# Display all picklist values regardless of record types on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have separated my picklist values in two records types.Now I want to display all the values 
of my picklist on a Visualforce page, however I am unable to do so. Please help me to achieve it. Useful links and hints are much appreciated.

Comment: Please check this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public with sharing class extension_user {
private String first_picklist_option = '- All -'; //first value to display in picklist
private final User user_object; //User sobject

public extension_user(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.user_object = (User)stdController.getRecord();
}

//builds a picklist of values based upon the passed information
public List<selectOption> getPickValues(Sobject object_name, String field_name, String first_val) {
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); //new list for holding all of the picklist options
    if ( first_val != null ) { //if there is a first value being provided
        options.add(new selectOption(first_val, first_val)); //add the first option
    }
    Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = object_name.getSObjectType(); //grab the sobject that was passed
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); //describe the sobject
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap(); //get a map of fields for the passed sobject
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get(field_name).getDescribe().getPickListValues(); //grab the list of picklist values for the passed field on the sobject
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) { //for all values in the picklist list
        options.add(new selectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue()));  //add the value and label to our final list
    }
    return options; //return the List
}

//return the picklist options for User.TimeZoneSidKey
public List<selectOption> getTimeZones() {
    return getPickValues(user_object, 'TimeZoneSidKey', first_picklist_option);
}

//return the picklist options for User.LocaleSidKey
public List<selectOption> getLocales() {
    return getPickValues(user_object, 'LocaleSidKey', first_picklist_option);
}

}
```

---

```
<apex:page standardController="User" extensions="extension_user">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Visualforce Sample" subtitle="Describe for Picklist Values" help="/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?loc=help"></apex:sectionHeader>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Criteria" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Time Zones" for="time_zones"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:selectList id="time_zones" size="1" title="Time Zones">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!TimeZones}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Locales" for="locale"></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:selectList id="locale" size="1" title="Locale">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Locales}"></apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```